# Mixed content issue with SCDF 2.11.1 with HAPROXY

Tags: haproxy, nginx-ingress, mixed-content

I have upgraded my SCDF server from 2.9.0 to 2.11.1, I have haproxy as reverse proxy to access SCDF server. While creating application I am unable to see drop down for springboot version. I am getting below error at browser.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://XXXX.XXXX.com/dashboard/index.html#/apps/add' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://c7ba24be1fe8904ecdc7-245ff539796eada4c09ab9b75307550a.r10.cf5.rackcdn.com/index.html'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Looks like SCDF need to get data from other resources via http and haproxy is blocking this.
I tried to add "http-response set-header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests" and
"http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https" in haproxy.conf but still issue persist.

Any solution for this? Any help is appreciated.

I tried to add "http-response set-header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests" and
"http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https" in haproxy.conf but still issue persist.

When I run scdf jar from local machine it run well but not with haproxy